# Jquery Datatable search in active grid only not ajax

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable plugin.

Question: 1
Search box.
I think ajax search is enabled if I use below code .
What I want?
I only want to search in active grid and I don't need ajax search.

Question: 2
Loading Icon is working perfectly but it is showing in the middle of the screen
when I have allot of records like 1000+ and my customers don't see that icon 
because it is in the middle .
Is there any way to get that icon to the Active screen of the user or 
with page scroll it will display ? any solution?

My code is below

```
 var table =  $('#all-member-table').DataTable( {
  scrollY: true,
   scroller: {
    loadingIndicator: true
  },
    oLanguage: {
        sProcessing: "<img src='https://itopia.com/wp-content/themes/itopia/img-cloud/loader.gif'>"
    },
    "lengthMenu": [ 200,300,500,1000 ],
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,

    "ajax": {

            url: "Job/all",
            // contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache : false,
            type  : "GET",

            data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
            // "data": '_token = ' + $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

            // beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            //      xhr.setRequestHeader('TOKEN', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
            // }
        },
        "columns": [
        { data: "job_no" },
        { data: "br" },
        { data: "Customer" },
        { data: "Manifest" },
        { data: "HBL" },
        { data: "created_at" },
        { data: "Status" },
        { data: "Options" }

    ]
});
```

Comment: DataTables can be a bit of a nightmare when it comes to these things bit is very customisable, with lots of options and API's. I remember doing a phonebook system with it.  I suggest playing around with them. https://datatables.net/reference/option/ they also have a forum which might help. https://datatables.net/forums/

Comment: @RichardHousham Thanks for the link,

Comment: If you not want `serverSide` processing, the set `serverSide: false` or do not  address the option at all.

Comment: as david said, you should remove the `serverSide` option if you're working client-side. the filtering option should work as-is with server-side off. About the loading img, maybe adding a high z-index to it? I'm not sure I understood correctly.